# Subtract Col A - Col B in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string-matching

I have two string columns in a dataframe and I'm looking to subtract common words in B from A.

```
A ->  Stack Overlflow is great            


B -> stack great


A-B -> overflow is
```

I have tried the following code. But it only works if the column B has one word.

```
df['A-B'] = [' '.join(set(a.split())-set(b.split())) for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]
```

Is there any change I can make so that it works when B has multiple words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Example `df` is:*

*`>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Stack Overlflow is great'], 'B': ['stack great']})`*

And you can use `apply`:

```
>>> df['A-B'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in x[0].split() if i.lower() not in x[1].split()]), axis=1)
>>> df
                          A            B           A-B
0  Stack Overlflow is great  stack great  Overlflow is
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`np.setdiff1d()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html):

```
df['A-B']=df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(np.setdiff1d(x['A'].lower().split(),
                                        x['B'].lower().split())),axis=1)
print(df)
```

---

```
                          A            B           A-B
0  Stack Overlflow is great  stack great  is overlflow
```

Your solution is almost there,just add [`series.str.lower()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.lower.html) when zipping them:

```
df['A-B']=[' '.join(set(a.split())-set(b.split())) 
        for a, b in zip(df['A'].str.lower(), df['B'].str.lower())]
```

---

Incase the series has duplicate strings, use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) which helps removing dupes as `set()` but maintaining the order too:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['Stack Overlflow is great is great'], 'B': ['stack great']})
                                  A            B
0  Stack Overlflow is great is great  stack great
```

---

```
from collections import OrderedDict
df['A-B']=[' '.join([ele for ele in OrderedDict.fromkeys(a) if ele not in b ])
 for a,b in zip(df.A.str.lower().str.split(),df.B.str.lower().str.split())]
print(df)
```

---

```
                                   A            B           A-B
0  Stack Overlflow is great is great  stack great  overlflow is
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing `setdiff1d`, reading through it right now :). Says nothing about sorting. Does it keep the original order?

Comment: I will, thanks. Good to know, since most will use `set` for this, but that will not keep the original order, so this is actually a good replacement for that

Comment: @Erfan it says "The result is sorted when assume_unique=False, but otherwise only sorted if the input is sorted." :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one liner:

```
' '.join(list(set(list(df.A.str.lower().str.split(' '))[0])-set(list(df.B.str.lower().str.split(' '))[0])))
```

just convert both the column values into lower case and split by space and put it into a list followed by taking a set of those lists and joining them by space.